# Is variable declared in AppDelegate accessible to all the other classes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios4, delegates

What exacly the AppDelegates method is given in Xcode??
I have so many classes in my app. Now i want is that i have `AudioStreamer` class and i have to use that class in most other classes... And I want to have only one instance of `AudioStreamer` class. So that it will be easy to handle one object.
Is it feasible to declare `AudioStreamer` class in `AppDelegate` file and make instance in that file only... Can I access that variable in all the other class.???

Comment: Make the `AudioStreamer` class a [singleton](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use very handy GCD (Grand Central Dispatch) functions to achieve Singleton behavior on these lines -

```
+ (AudioStreamer*) defaultStreamer {
    static AudioStreamer* defaultStreamer = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        defaultStreamer = [[AudioStreamer alloc] init];
    });
    return defaultStreamer; 
}
```

Comment: +1 Although I will stay with classical singleton, this is an interesting and creative approach - I'll keep it in the back of my head :-)

Comment: So when i will call this method from different classes.. will it give me only one same instance everytime?? I want to refer to only one instance everytime..

Comment: @Dhiren - Yes, thats correct! you would always have a 'single' instance of your AudioStreamer throughout the app.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend a [singleton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern) so that only one instance is created and shared by all clients.

I suggest Matt Galaghers posting about singletons and his downloadable SynthesizeSingleton.h:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html

Comment: So exactly where should i implement this singleton??? will it be good to declare in AppDelegate

Comment: No just in AudioStreamer. Declare a class method "+(AudioStreamer) sharedAudioStreamer", include SyntesizeSingleton.h in .m file and than you can access your singleton instance with [AudioStreamer sharedAudioStreamer]. I changed the original file a bit so that my access method is always called sharedInstance and not sharedWhatEver, but do it as you like it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also access the objects declared as properties in appDelegate thru out ur app like this.

```
myFirstAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
myStr=[appDelegate.mainArray objectAtIndex:1];
```

In the above example I have shown how to access the array which I have declared and retained in appDelegate class. In this way you can access any objects you want which are declared as properties,thru out ur app. Hope this helps.

Comment: @Dhiren Shah Chk this answer. hope it helps u. Happy coding